# Do static constructors get called when using the designer?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, static-constructor

I want to run some registration code, both at run time AND at design time. 
The best way, to me, appeared to be to use a static constructor, but it does not appear to be run.

```
public class MyComponent : Component 
{
    static string someVar = "Static constructor not yet run";

    static MyComponent() 
    {
        someVar = "Static constuctor run";
    }

    public MyComponent()
    {
        //Do some constructor things
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make a static constructor run at design time? 
If not is there an accepted pattern for doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, static constructor will run regardless of design time or run time. A simple test can prove it.

```
public class MyComponent : Component
{
    static string someVar = "Static constructor not yet run";

    static MyComponent()
    {
        someVar = "Static constructor run";
        MessageBox.Show(someVar);
    }

    public MyComponent()
    {
        //Do some constructor things
    }
}
```

Now add the component in to the designer, and Build the project. You'll see message box with message *Static constructor run*.

Comment: @Landerah While that answers your question, I believe this is a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you can explain what you're trying to achieve you may get good answers.

Comment: Ah my mistake! I was using the same method as you to test whether the function was called but I did not rebuild my project. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

This is what the MSDN has to say about [static constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class
>   before the first instance is created or any static members are
>   referenced.
>
> A static constructor cannot be called directly.
>
> The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in
>   the program.

Basically, you cannot control it from your code by calling it as you would a normal method.

An example on how they work:

```
    public class Bus
    {
        // Static variable used by all Bus instances. 
        // Represents the time the first bus of the day starts its route. 
        protected static readonly DateTime globalStartTime;

        // Property for the number of each bus. 
        protected int RouteNumber { get; set; }

        // Static constructor to initialize the static variable. 
        // It is invoked before the first instance constructor is run. 
        static Bus()
        {
            globalStartTime = DateTime.Now;

            // The following statement produces the first line of output,  
            // and the line occurs only once.
            Console.WriteLine("Static constructor sets global start time to {0}",
                globalStartTime.ToLongTimeString());
        }

        // Instance constructor. 
        public Bus(int routeNum)
        {
            RouteNumber = routeNum;
            Console.WriteLine("Bus #{0} is created.", RouteNumber);
        }

        // Instance method. 
        public void Drive()
        {
            TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - globalStartTime;

            // For demonstration purposes we treat milliseconds as minutes to simulate 
            // actual bus times. Do not do this in your actual bus schedule program!
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is starting its route {1:N2} minutes after global start time {2}.",
                                    this.RouteNumber,
                                    elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds,
                                    globalStartTime.ToShortTimeString());
        }
    }

    class TestBus
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // The creation of this instance activates the static constructor.
            Bus bus1 = new Bus(71);

            // Create a second bus.
            Bus bus2 = new Bus(72);

            // Send bus1 on its way.
            bus1.Drive();

            // Wait for bus2 to warm up.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);

            // Send bus2 on its way.
            bus2.Drive();

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    /* Sample output:
        Static constructor sets global start time to 3:57:08 PM.
        Bus #71 is created.
        Bus #72 is created.
        71 is starting its route 6.00 minutes after global start time 3:57 PM.
        72 is starting its route 31.00 minutes after global start time 3:57 PM.      
   */
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but we **do** know that a static constuctor should have been called before the normal constructor, and this is what my question was referring to.